# Django mysql error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using `mysql-python`. Here's my settings.py

```
import os, sys

abspath = lambda *p: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*p))

PROJECT_ROOT = abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
USERENA_MODULE_PATH = abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, '..')
sys.path.insert(0, USERENA_MODULE_PATH)

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('me', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'DATABASE_USER': 'root',
        'DATABASE_PASSWORD': 'pass',
    }
}

if DEBUG:
    # Use the Python SMTP debugging server. You can run it with:
    # ``python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025``.
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mygmail@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '12345'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('nl', ugettext('Dutch')),
    ('fr', ugettext('French')),
    ('pl', ugettext('Polish')),
    ('pt', ugettext('Portugese')),
    ('es', ugettext('Spanish')),
)

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
DOCUMENT_ROOT = abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'docs')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

SECRET_KEY = 'sx405#tc)5m@s#^jh5l7$k#cl3ekg)jtbo2ds(n(kw@gp0t7x@'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'userena.middleware.UserenaLocaleMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'userena.backends.UserenaAuthenticationBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'demo_project.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'guardian',
    'south',
    'userena',
    'userena.contrib.umessages',
    'demo_project.profiles',
)

# Userena settings
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/%(username)s/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/signin/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/accounts/signout/'
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile'

USERENA_DISABLE_PROFILE_LIST = True
USERENA_MUGSHOT_SIZE = 140

# Test settings
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner'
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False

# Guardian
ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
```

when i run `syncdb` i see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 21, in <module>
    mod = import_module(app)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 51, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.mysql instead.
Error was: No module named mysql.base
```

if i replace `'ENGINE': 'mysql' with`django.db.backends.mysql` i see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 411, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myname/.django-projects/userena/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'myname'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replacing 'ENGINE': 'mysql' with django.db.backends.mysql` is correct.

Now, you have to change from:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'DATABASE_USER': 'root',
        'DATABASE_PASSWORD': 'pass',
    }
}
```

to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    }
}
```